# Php copy video from remote URL and show progress

Tags: php, copy, progress-bar

I want to copy files from remote URL specifically video files but also want to show the progress of copy.

My current code is:

```
$remote = fopen('remote-file', 'r');
$local = fopen('local-file', 'w');

    $read_bytes = 0;
    while(!feof($remote)) {
      $buffer = fread($remote, 2048);
      fwrite($local, $buffer);

      $read_bytes += 2048;

      //Use $filesize as calculated earlier to get the progress percentage
      $progress = min(100, 100 * $read_bytes / $filesize);
      //you'll need some way to send $progress to the browser.
      //maybe save it to a file and then let an Ajax call check it?
    }
    fclose($remote);
    fclose($local);
```

To get file size I'm using this method.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php#92462

But the filesize which I'm getting for 6.58 MB file is 1056 and because of this it always shows progress as 100.

How should I get the correct file size of remote URL?

Comment: I think you should ask a new question. Your edit changes the your question to something completely different. First version was correctly closed as duplicate by @HaimEvgi and after your edit your question is off-topic ("Why isn't this code working" - without MCVE). See [help] for more details.